# Is there a difference between "care about" one vs "care for" one?

Tags: meaning, prepositions, differences

One person says:"You don't care about me!"
Another replies: "I care deeply for you."

Instead of replying "I care deeply about you," the replier says "I care deeply for you."

Is there a difference between "care about" one vs "care for" one?

Comment: Hello, spacenet. Have you tried to find examples and example sentences in dictionaries?

Comment: In some constructions, at least, I would read the two expressions as having distinctly different meanings. "I don't care for macrobiotic food" = "I don't like [the taste of] it." "I don't care about macrobiotic food" = "the topic doesn't interest me."

Comment: _Care for_ can also mean _look after_.